# Div content disappears on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a live chat widget (Chatlio.com) to a div (of a total of 3 divs) to my Bootstrap-project on localhost:

```
<div id="chatlioWidgetPlaceholder" style="margin: auto; height:400px; width:100%;"></div>
```

The chat shows up nicely on desktop view, fully functional and displays correctly in its div at the bottom left:

[image]

...but once I go down to mobile view with the inspector's "Device mode", the chat doesn't show up and I can't see the reason why!

[image]

I have separate wrappers for desktop and mobile view (due to the wanted behavior of the divs in Bootstrap I have the chat widget in Div 2 on Desktop view and in Div 1 in mobile view) and not sure if that is what causes it.

I have placed all HTML and CSS in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/wLnxgo69/

Comment: To improve your code: "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" here you can remove the col-sm-12 and the col-lg-6, because the smaller formats have the same size. Same as "col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12", you can remove the md and lg here

Comment: @RPelzer  ...oh thank you! I never thought of it that way :) Good learning

Answer (score 0):

> I have separate wrappers for desktop and mobile view (due to the
>   wanted behavior of the divs in Bootstrap I have the chat widget in Div
>   2 on Desktop view and in Div 1 in mobile view) and not sure if that is
>   what causes it.

Yes it probably is. I can't see in the Chatlio documentation how it is initialised but I am guessing the code might look something like (jQuery)

```
$('#chatlioWidgetPlaceholder').chatlio();
```

This will only initialise Chatlio on the first `#chatlioWidgetPlaceholder` on the page (your desktop one).

My instinct is to clean up the HTML so you don't need two wrappers – that code is going to be hard to maintain in the long run anyway – but failing that you might see whether Chatlio will allow you to target an element by class rather than ID or you might just need a second widget.

Comment: ....You are right! I just noticed that. So I think my option is to have the js file load first and then move it to desired div with addClass()

Answer (score 0):

There is a code example for the `chatlio.ready` event that I think illustrates what you need to do to move the chat widget from one DOM container to another: https://chatlio.com/docs/api-v1/#api-custom-events-ready – is that what you need?

Your fiddle does not contain the embed code directly making it a little tricky to help you out; if the above doesn't work do you mind adding it?